# Simple way to add sudo to docker image

Tags: docker, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I'm trying to create a way to easily test my installation scripts for Ubuntu. What I'm doing now is that I create a temporary docker container like this.
`docker run --rm -it ubuntu bash` and then copy in my script. This gives me a fresh ubuntu install, which instantly gets created and then removed on exit.

The problem is that i can't include the word **sudo** in my installation script without the script throwing errors. I need to use sudo in real world applications, so I can't remove it.

Is there some simple way to add sudo functionality, or "Ubuntu-like-images" which has this?

Comment: Are you trying to execute docker commands without sudo?

Comment: The commands are all inside my shell scripts, and they are not docker commands.

Comment: `apt-get install -y sudo`? `docker run --rm -it ubuntu bash -c 'apt-get install -y sudo && bash'`?

Comment: You don't need `sudo` in Docker at all.  `docker run -u root your-image` and you're root.  In most images the default user is root as well.  (You also wouldn't typically use the unmodified `ubuntu` image; instead, write a Dockerfile that `COPY`s your script in, and you won't have to keep repeating the copy step every time you launch the container.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@KamilCuk provided the solution, where all i needed was just to install sudo.

`apt update && apt-get install -y sudo`